# convolutions and mollification of functions in $L^1_{\text{loc}}(\Omega)$

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

The following is from the appendix in Leoni's *[First Course in Sobolev Spaces](http://www.ams.org/bookstore-getitem/item=gsm-105)*:

[image]

[image]

Here is my **question**:

> Could anybody explain what is the meaning of "$u_\varepsilon$ is well-defined"? What is wrong if $\varepsilon\geq \hbox{dist} (x,\partial\Omega)$?

Comment: A small note: the author's last name is "Leoni", not "Leonin".

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro: Ah, thanks for the correction!

Comment: (it is more or less obvious from the definition)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have the definition

$$u_{\varepsilon}(x) = \int_{\Omega} \varphi_{\varepsilon}(x-y)\, u(y)\,dy.$$

For $u_{\varepsilon}(x)$ to be well-defined, that integral needs to exist. Since measurability is given, the problem is whether

$$\int_{\Omega} \varphi_{\varepsilon}(x-y)\,\lvert u(y)\rvert\,dy < +\infty.$$

If we required $u \in L^1(\Omega)$, or just $\tilde{u} \in L^1_{\text{loc}}(\mathbb{R}^N)$, where $\tilde{u}$ is the trivial extension of $u$ to $\mathbb{R}^N$, then there would be no problem. But as we only require $u \in L^1_{\text{loc}}(\Omega)$, it can be that $u$ grows too fast near $\partial \Omega$.

If $\varepsilon < \operatorname{dist}(x,\partial \Omega)$, then the integrand is nonzero only on a compact subset of $\Omega$ - namely $\overline{B(x,\varepsilon)}$ - and the boundedness of $\varphi$ together with the definition of $L^1_{\text{loc}}(\Omega)$ ensure the existence of the integral.

If $\varepsilon \geqslant \operatorname{dist}(x,\partial \Omega)$, then $\Omega \cap \overline{B(x,\varepsilon)}$ reaches $\partial \Omega$, and the growth of $\lvert u\rvert$ near $\partial \Omega$ may cause the integral to not exist.

Comment: So according to the answer, if $u\in L^1(\Omega)$, one can always consider the mollification in the whole $\Omega$ instead of $\Omega_\varepsilon$, is that correct?

Comment: Yes, if $u \in L^1(\Omega)$ then $\tilde{u} \in L^1(\mathbb{R}^N)$, where $\tilde{u}$ is the trivial extension of $u$, and we can look at the restriction of $\tilde{u}\ast \varphi_{\varepsilon}$ to $\Omega$. Though often one can find better extensions $v$ of $u$ so that $v \ast \varphi_{\varepsilon}$ is a better approximation to $u$ on $\Omega\setminus \Omega_{\varepsilon}$ than $\tilde{u}\ast \varphi_{\varepsilon}$. For actual computations, that can be useful (faster convergence).

Comment: My previous comment does not quite reflect my concern and I have just posted a related [question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1969871/9464). So if $u\in L^1(\Omega)$, the as you said one can *define* $u_\epsilon$ on the whole $\Omega$. How about the regularity? Does one still have $u_\epsilon\in C^\infty(\Omega)$? (Would you elaborate the point "better extensions $v$ of $u$"? Are you saying that $\tilde{u}*\varphi_\epsilon$ might be not good on $\Omega\setminus\Omega_\epsilon$?)

Comment: The text in your question only assumes $\varphi \in L^1(\mathbb{R}^N)$, that's not enough regularity to even guarantee that $u_{\varepsilon}$ is continuous. But if you take $\varphi \in C_c^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^N)$, then $f \ast \varphi_{\varepsilon} \in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^N)$ for every $f \in L^1_{\text{loc}}(\mathbb{R}^N)$, hence $\tilde{u}\ast \varphi_{\varepsilon}$ is smooth, and so is its restriction to $\Omega$.

Comment: @Daniel Fischer Is  $C^{\infty}$  subset in $L^1_{loc}$ in general ?

Comment: @DanielFischer Why the convolution is not defined if $\text{dist}(x, \partial\Omega)\le \varepsilon$?