# Properties of mollification for integrable functions

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

The following is a theorem regarding the mollification of *locally* integrable functions.

> [image]

According to the [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1518982/9464) of a previous [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1518395/9464), if $f$ is integrable on $U$, i.e. $f\in L^1(U)$, then $f^\epsilon=\eta_\epsilon*f$ is well-defined on $U$ (instead of only in $U_\epsilon$).

Here is my **question**:

> Suppose $f\in L^1(U)$. Then do we have $f^\epsilon\in C^\infty(U)$?

---

Here are the notations used above:

> [image]

Comment: Yes, if $f \in L^1(U)$, you can without loss of generality assume $U = \mathbb{R}^n$, for you can look at $$\tilde{f}(x) = \begin{cases} f(x) &, x \in U \\ \; 0 &, x \notin U.\end{cases}$$

Comment: Then one would have a very [quick proof](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1969895/9464) regarding the approximation of $W^{k,p}(U)$ by $C^\infty(U)$ functions when $U$ is bounded?!

Comment: Only for nice enough $U$ (or $k = 0$). If $U$ is bad, you can have problems with the derivatives, a partial derivative of $\tilde{u}\ast \varphi_{\varepsilon}$ need not approximate the corresponding weak derivative of $u$, boundary effects may interfere.

Comment: What's wrong with the partial derivative? On the whole domain $U$ one no longer has the relation $D^\alpha u^\epsilon=\eta_\epsilon*D^\alpha u$, which would give the desired partial derivative approximation?

Comment: We have $D^\alpha\tilde u^\varepsilon=\eta_\varepsilon\ast D^\alpha\tilde u$ where $D^\alpha\tilde u$ is the _distributional derivative_ of $\tilde u$. And that distributional derivative has a part coming from the cut-off at $\partial U$. Coming to think of it, taking the trivial extension, that can destroy the $L^p(U)$ approximation for the derivatives even for nice boundaries. Consider $u\in W^{1,1}([-1,1]),\, u(x)=1$. Then you get $(\tilde{u}^{\varepsilon})'=(\delta_{-1}-\delta_1)\ast\eta_\varepsilon$, and for $\varepsilon\leqslant 1/2$, the $L^1$-norm of the derivative is $1$, but $Du=0$.

Comment: There are two points that I don't quite follow you. (1) If $f\in L^1(U)$, then one can define the mollification of $f$ on $U$ by the formula $f^\epsilon(x)=\int_U\eta_\epsilon(x-y)f(y)\ dy$ where $x\in U$. Why would one need to consider the zero extension of $f$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$? (2) In the identity $D^\alpha u^\epsilon=\eta_\epsilon*D^\alpha u$, the LHS is the classical partial derivative since we agree that $u^\epsilon\in C^\infty(U)$, not only $u^\epsilon\in C^\infty(U_\epsilon)$.

Comment: On the RHS, $D^\alpha u$ is the weak derivative which is an $L^p(U)$ function by definition and thus $L^1(U)$ since $U$ is bounded. Why, again, the extension $\tilde{u}$ is involved?

Comment: Your formula for $f^{\varepsilon}$ is precisely $(\eta_{\varepsilon}\ast \tilde{f})(x) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \eta_{\varepsilon}(x-y) \tilde{f}(y)\,dy$. And the problem is that in general we don't have $D^{\alpha}(u^{\varepsilon}) = \eta_{\varepsilon} \ast \widetilde{D^{\alpha}u}$ if we take the weak derivative of $u$ on the right hand side. The $(D^{\alpha}f)\ast g = D^{\alpha}(f \ast g) = f \ast D^{\alpha} g$ rule requires a convolution (and holds for distributional derivatives, provided all these convolutions make sense as convolutions of distributions), and for a convolution, you need

Comment: globally defined partners. That's why we extend, and we must take the distributional derivative of the extension.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have full differentiability, because the derivatives of the convolution can be put on the mollifier:
$$
          \frac{d}{dx_j}\int_{U}\eta_{\epsilon}(x-y)f(y)dy=\int_{U}(\eta_{\epsilon})_j(x-y)f(y)dy.
$$
This falls under the standard full-space mollifier; all you have to do is extend $f$ to $0$ outside of $U$ and then integrate over free space. All orders and mixes of derivatives exist in free space for such an integral, provided $f \in L^1(U)$.