# Can Evans's proof for the theorem regarding global approximation of Sobolev functions be significantly simplified?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

> [image]
>   Here $U$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Above is a theorem regarding approximation of Sobolev functions in Evans's Partial Differential Equations. When I tried to the recover the proof on my own, I found that the proof *might* be much shorter than the one in the book. But it looks too simple to be true and I'm wondering if there is a big gap there.

---

Here is my argument. Suppose $u\in W^{k,p}(U)$. Then $u\in L^p(U)$ by definition and thus $u\in L^1(U)$ since $U$ is bounded. Now according to the answer and comments to the following questions:

- [convolutions and mollification of functions in $L^1_{\text{loc}}(\Omega)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1518395/9464)
- [Properties of mollification for integrable functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1969871/9464)

one can define the mollification $u^\epsilon=\eta_\epsilon*u$ on $U$ such that $u_\epsilon\in C^\infty(U)$. Moreover, since 
$$
D^\alpha u^\epsilon=\eta_\epsilon*D^\alpha u \quad\textrm{in  } U, 
$$
one has 
$$
\|u^\epsilon-u\|_{W^{k,p}(U)}^p=\sum \|D^\alpha u^\epsilon-D^\alpha u\|_{L^p(U)}^p\to 0.
$$

> Could anyone identify if there is any serious mistake in the above argument?

---

[**Added**:]A possible naive analogy I make in the above argument is as the following. First of all, I have the following facts

- $D^\alpha u^\epsilon=\eta_\epsilon*D^\alpha$ in $\color{blue}{U_\epsilon}$, where the definition can be seen in the linked question.
- Also, $D^\alpha u^\epsilon\to D^\alpha u$ in $L^p(V)$ for any $V\Subset U$.

Now that I can do mollification on the entire domain $U$ instead of just $U_\epsilon$, I just *guess* one might have

- $D^\alpha u^\epsilon=\eta_\epsilon*D^\alpha u$ in $\color{blue}{U}$.
- and $D^\alpha u^\epsilon\to D^\alpha u$ in $L^p(U)$.

---

For the original "long" proof of THEOREM 2 by Evans, see this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1521739/9464).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**NOTE**. The numbering of equations is not progressive because of successive edits. I have left the original numbering so that comments stay understandable.

---

If you perform the mollification in the brutal way 
$$
u^\epsilon(x)= \int_{\mathbb R^n} \eta_\epsilon(x-y)u(y)\mathbf 1_{y\in U}\, dy,\quad x\in U $$ 
that is, setting $u$ to be equal to $0$ outside $U$, then the last two properties mentioned in your question need not hold in the whole domain $U$.

For a concrete example consider the space $W^{1,2}(-1, 1)$ and the constant function $u(x)=\mathbf 1_{|x|\le 1}.$ You have that 
$$\frac{du}{dx} \equiv 0\quad \text{in } U.$$ 
When you perform the brutal mollification you get 
$$\frac{d}{dx} \left( u\ast \eta_\epsilon\right)(x)= \eta_\epsilon(x+1) - \eta_\epsilon(x-1)\tag{2}$$
This already shows that the desired property 
$$\tag{!!!}\frac{d}{dx}\left( u\ast \eta_\epsilon\right) = \frac{du}{dx}\ast \eta_\epsilon\quad \text{in }U$$ 
needs not hold in $U$. Moreover, you can easily check that the $L^2(-1, 1)$ norm of (2) blows up to infinity as $\epsilon\downarrow 0$. This shows that the desired property 
$$\tag{!!!}\left
\| \frac{d}{dx}u\ast\eta_\epsilon - \frac{du}{dx}\right\|_{L^2(U)}\to 0$$ needs not hold either.

Note that if you exclude a small neighborhood of $\{-1, +1\}$, that is, if you consider $U_\delta= (-1+\delta, 1-\delta)$ instead of $U$, then both properties $(!!!)$ do hold (the first holds provided $\epsilon < \delta$). That's why Evans worries about taking mollifications an epsilon away from the boundary of $U$.

**Final remark**. The distributional point of view provides some more insight. Note that, if you extend $u$ to be zero outside of $U$and consider the result as a distribution on $\mathbb R$, then its derivative is equal to 
$$\frac{ du}{dx} = \delta(x+1)-\delta(x-1).\tag{1}$$
The brutal extension produced two Dirac deltas in the first derivative. Those are responsible for the failure of properties $(!!!)$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm trying to follow you. So according to the answer, is it not true that $D^\alpha u^\epsilon=\eta_\epsilon*D^\alpha u$ in $\color{blue}{U}$?

Comment: Yes, that's a first problem, if you do not consider distributions. In the present case, for example, $\frac{d}{dx} u \equiv 0$ in $U$. But it is not true that $\frac{d}{dx}\left( u\ast \zeta_\epsilon\right) \equiv 0$. In the limit as $\epsilon \to 0$, things get even worse as the mollification's $L^2$ norm blows up to infinity. If you do not know about distributions, try computing the derivative of $u\ast \zeta_\epsilon$ manually.

Comment: +1 Thanks! I know only very basic definitions regarding distributions and Evans tries to avoid using the language of distribution in his book. Let me try the computation to see what is really going on and come back later.

Comment: Do you mean $\eta_\epsilon$ for $\zeta_\epsilon$ in your answer?

Comment: Without using the language of distributions,  I now can see by direct computation that why $\frac{d}{dx}(u*\eta_\epsilon)\equiv0$ on $U$ is *not* true. Is it (1) that gives you the shortcut to get (2) or do you use (1) somewhere else?

Comment: Of course $\zeta$ should be $\eta$ and the distributional point of view is not needed, I only use it to compute $\frac d{dx} u\ast \eta_\epsilon$. I am editing the answer.

Comment: Also, the distributional way gives a much faster way to get $\frac{d}{dx}(u*\eta_\epsilon)$ I suppose.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro...an you teach me sobolev space sir